# How to change the state in react native?

Tags: react-native, state, render

I am trying to detect the orientation of my device and I've found some code to perform this and I think it works properly. What I want now is to render my output which is the degree of the orientation but it doesn't give me expected output. I just want to want to put the degree into a state and then change it. In the end, I want to show this on my phone app.

I have tried to do this by using this.setState ({degree:degree}) after initializing a state of the degree in the very beginning of the code but it came to nothing in the end.

```
export default class orientation extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      degree: 0
    };

    const subscribtion = orientationObservable.subscribe(
      // angle range [-180, 180]
      degree => this.setState{(degree:degree)}
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
      subscribtion.unsubscribe();
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.degree}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I just want to know how to put "degree" into a state, be able to change it and then render it to show it in the app. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/understanding-react-setstate/  Some help.

Comment: where do you get `orientationObservable` ?

Comment: You are not getting error for doing `this.setState{(degree:degree)}`? it should be `this.setState({degree:degree})`